# How to drop a columnm postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My code:

```
drop table movie;

CREATE TABLE movie
(
imdib varchar NOT NULL,
name varchar NOT NULL,
year integer,
rating varchar,
votes varchar,
runtime varchar,
directors varchar,
actors varchar,
genres varchar
);


 COPY movies FROM '/home/max/Schreibtisch/imdb_top100.txt' (DELIMITER E'\t');

 COPY movies FROM '/home/max/Schreibtisch/imdb_top100t_2015-06-18.csv' (DELIMITER E'\t', FORMAT CSV);


SELECT actors, unnest(string_to_array(actors, '|')) AS Schauspieler from kinofilme;
SELECT directors, unnest(string_to_array(directors, '|')) AS Regisseure from movies;
SELECT genres, unnest(string_to_array(genres, '|')) AS Genrees from movies;
```

Explaination for the last 3 statements: Genres, actors and directors is delimited with a '| ( for example: Genre: Action|Drama|Thriller)
But I wanted getting only one genre from genres( e.g getting only Action from Action|Drama|Thriller) that is why I used unnest(string_to_array). The problem is the output. When I use `SELECT genres, unnest(string_to_array(genres, '|')) AS Genrees from movies;`   the output is:

Genres (character varying)______________Genrees(text)

1. Crime|Drama _____________________Crime
2. Crime|Drama _____________________ Drama
3. Action|Drama _____________________ Action
4. Action|Drama ______________________Drama

I wanna drop the first column"Genres" because I do not need it for select statements. I only need the second column "Genrees" where each single Genre is shown. How to do drop that first left colunn named"Genres" or how to make it "disappear" ? Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Are you looking for `alter table drop column`?

Comment: I tried this but then I can not create my table, because "genre" is missing then.

Comment: @Blnpwr What is the problem with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT regexp_replace(genres,'\|.*','') AS Genrees from movies;
```

This will return

```
Crime
Action
```

for your example